# Detecting IBeacon works in LogCat but not on Phone

Tags: ibeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

I'm working on an `Android` app that detects an `iBeacon`. Now my problem is that in the `LogCat` I can see the correct name of the beacon together with the IP-address

> BtGatt.btif btif_gatc_update_properties BLE device name=.. BtGatt
>   GattService onScanResult()  IP-address

But the `onBeaconServiceConnect()` method still enters the `else` part as the collection ( `Size` is 0). I have already read the thread concerning this topic in here and searched the internt but couln't find an answer.

**My Code:**

```
public class RangingActivity extends Activity implements BeaconConsumer {
  protected static final String TAG = "RangingActivity";
  private BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
  private BluetoothAdapter btAdapt;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ranging);

    beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1000);
    beaconManager.bind(this);

  }
  @Override 
  protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    beaconManager.unbind(this);
  }
  @Override 
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
  }
  @Override 
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
  }

  @Override
  public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
    public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
        logToDisplay("Number of beacons detected: "+beacons.size());
        if (beacons.size() > 0) {
            EditText editText = (EditText)RangingActivity.this
                    .findViewById(R.id.rangingText);
            Beacon firstBeacon = beacons.iterator().next();
            logToDisplay("The first beacon "+firstBeacon.toString());
        }else{
            logToDisplay("No beacon");
        }
    }

    });

    try {
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));
    } catch (RemoteException e) {   }
}
private void logToDisplay(final String line) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            EditText editText = (EditText)RangingActivity.this
                    .findViewById(R.id.rangingText);
            editText.append(line+"\n");             
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The log line you mention in LogCat indicates that Android's bluetooth stack saw a Bluetooth LE device.  It does not mean that the bluetooth device it saw is a recognizable beacon.

The most likely explanation is that you do not have any beacons transmitting that the library will recognize.  Understand that by default, the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) only detects AltBeacons, a transmission format that is intellectual-property free.  If you want the library to detect proprietary beacons, then you need to configure it with a custom `BeaconParser`.  This is actually very easy to do.  Carefully read the [documentation](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/javadoc/org/altbeacon/beacon/BeaconParser.html) for the `setBeaconLayout` method on how to do this.

If this does not solve your problem and you wish to debug this further, try enabling debug logging in the library to get more information in LogCat.  You can do this by adding a line to your `onCreate` method:

```
beaconManager.setDebug(true);
```